# sending several method parameters vs sending one then decoding in destination method

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, method-parameters

I have an interesting decision I would like some help with.

I am forming a request to my DB from a view where I select several (18) values (not all are required to be selected), these values will then be sent from my view to my request variable where I put the parameters into an XML request.

So I am wondering do I create a method with 18 parameters that are not necessarily all required!?? or create a single parameter out of all of the possible variables, send the data over to the destination then decode there?

example of how this is going to work.

- UIViewController, select all values needed.
- Hit send button which has a method attached to it, then sends all the values off to my requestController
- request controller then sends XML to DB as a request.

so my question is whats the best way to send my values from one method to another.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially if it's going to become xml eventually, an NSDictionary is probably your best bet.  Fill it with keys - which can eventually become your xml tags - and the values collected by the view.  It's one param to pass, and a missing key/value is a zero overhead way to send an optional param that isn't present.

Comment: okay cool.. I was thinking as much :) cheers for the confirmation.